Selenium interaction in Python with class selectric in HTML
I'm trying to automate an extraction of data from a site where i put some params and then I extract the results and elaborate it.
I have a problem when I try to insert a value in selectric class.
The class I'm trying to insert data in is:
`

Sesso
Uomini
Donne
                Sesso▾SessoUominiDonne
            `
And my code is:
select_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='solr[sesso]']") select_object = Select(select_element) select_object.select_by_value("M")
And this gives me the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: {"status":11,"value":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"} (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.127)
